# multiple infowindows on a Google Maps Array

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

(PS- yes, I looked at this related stackoverflow and [this blog](http://you.arenot.me/2010/06/29/google-maps-api-v3-0-multiple-markers-multiple-infowindows/) and neither fixed my issue, maybe I'm making some obvious mistake elsewhere?)

I'm trying to get multiple different infowindows to show up on my google map. When my listener is set to:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
         infoWindow.setContent( this.html );
         infoWindow.open( map, this );
});
```

Then, infowindows pop up completely blank for all of the markers.

When my listener is set to just:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
         infoWindow.open( map, this );
});
```

Then infowindows pop up with titles, but it's only the last title from each array that shows up on all of the markers.

Here's the totality of my google maps javascript code:

```html
      function initAutocomplete() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: 35.6895, lng: 139.6917},
          zoom: 13,
          mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
        });  

       // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
        var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
        var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

        /*var markers = [];*/
        // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
        // more details for that place.
        searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
          var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

          if (places.length == 0) {
            return;
          }

          // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
          var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
          places.forEach(function(place) {
            if (!place.geometry) {
              console.log("Returned place contains no geometry");
              return;
            }

            if (place.geometry.viewport) {
              // Only geocodes have viewport.
              bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
            } else {
              bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
            }
          });
          map.fitBounds(bounds);
        });
        
    setMarkers(map, food);
    setMarkers(map, views);    
}    
    
    
var views = [
//Tokyo     
  ['Tokyu Plaza Omotesando Harajuku', 35.66871, 139.70598, 0],
  ['Shinjuku', 35.69384, 139.70354, 0],
  ['Robot Restaurant', 35.69431, 139.70284, 0],
  ['Shinjuku Crossing Intersection', 35.65945, 139.70061, 0],
  ['Starbucks Tokyu Plaza', 35.66886, 139.70603, 0]     
];          
    
var food = [
//Tokyo    
  ['2Chome Tsukemen Gachi', 35.69126, 139.70853, 1],
  ['Tsukiji Fish Market', 35.66548, 139.77066, 1],
  ['Tonkatsu Tonki', 35.6336, 139.71429, 1],
];

function setMarkers(map, locations) {
  // Add markers to the map
  var shape = {
      coord: [1, 1, 1, 20, 18, 20, 18 , 1],
      type: 'poly'
  };
  for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    var locale = locations[i];
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(locale[1], locale[2]);
    var icon_to_use;
    var infowindow = null;  
    if(locale[3] < 1 ){
      icon_to_use = new google.maps.MarkerImage('img/views.png', new google.maps.Size(40, 40), new google.maps.Point(0,0), new google.maps.Point(0, 32));
    }
      else {
      icon_to_use = new google.maps.MarkerImage('img/food.png', new google.maps.Size(40, 40), new google.maps.Point(0,0), new google.maps.Point(0, 32));
    }
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map,
        icon: icon_to_use,
        info: locale[0],
        shape: shape,
        zIndex: locale[3] //someday I will tie this zIndex to how a place is ranked//    
    }); 
     infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: locale[0]
    });
     google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
         infoWindow.setContent( this.html );
         infoWindow.open( map, this );
    });  
  }
}
```

How do I get the unique titles to show up in their respective infowindows?

Comment: BTW - `MarkerImage` was deprecated and removed from the documentation in favor of the anonymous `Icon` object many years ago.

Answer (score 1):

Your markers don't have a `html` property, so this doesn't set any content in the InfoWindow:

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
     infoWindow.setContent( this.html );
     infoWindow.open( map, this );
});
```

Use the `info` property (which is what it looks like you want), or rename that to `html`:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: myLatLng,
  map: map,
  icon: icon_to_use,
  info: locale[0]
});

 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
     infoWindow.setContent( this.info);
     infoWindow.open( map, this );
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/pv18xemt/1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initAutocomplete() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {
      lat: 35.6895,
      lng: 139.6917
    },
    zoom: 13,
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
  });
  // create the shared InfoWindow
  infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
  var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
  var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

  // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
  // more details for that place.
  searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
    var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

    if (places.length == 0) {
      return;
    }

    // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    places.forEach(function(place) {
      if (!place.geometry) {
        console.log("Returned place contains no geometry");
        return;
      }

      if (place.geometry.viewport) {
        // Only geocodes have viewport.
        bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
      } else {
        bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
      }
    });
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  });

  setMarkers(map, food);
  setMarkers(map, views);
}


var views = [
  //Tokyo     
  ['Tokyu Plaza Omotesando Harajuku', 35.66871, 139.70598, 0],
  ['Shinjuku', 35.69384, 139.70354, 0],
  ['Robot Restaurant', 35.69431, 139.70284, 0],
  ['Shinjuku Crossing Intersection', 35.65945, 139.70061, 0],
  ['Starbucks Tokyu Plaza', 35.66886, 139.70603, 0]
];

var food = [
  //Tokyo    
  ['2Chome Tsukemen Gachi', 35.69126, 139.70853, 1],
  ['Tsukiji Fish Market', 35.66548, 139.77066, 1],
  ['Tonkatsu Tonki', 35.6336, 139.71429, 1],
];

function setMarkers(map, locations) {
  // Add markers to the map
  for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    var locale = locations[i];
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(locale[1], locale[2]);
    var icon_to_use;
    var infowindow = null;
    if (locale[3] < 1) {
      icon_to_use = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png';
    } else {
      icon_to_use = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/green.png';
    }
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatLng,
      map: map,
      icon: icon_to_use,
      info: locale[0],
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      infoWindow.setContent(this.info);
      infoWindow.open(map, this);
    });
  }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initAutocomplete);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry,places"></script>
<input id="pac-input" />
<div id="map"></div>
```